# Problems with floating a list inside a div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to float a ul inside a div and nothing seems to be working. Am I missing something?

Is there a problem with me using flexbox? I've tried different selectors like .menu ul{} and have given the ul a class but nothing seems to be working.

I have also tried to get rid of the div elements nested inside the ul, but that didn't fix the problem.

Tried assigning a display: block to the menu div as well as a height and width but that didn't do anything.

I'm sure there is something obvioues that I'm missing but I can't figure it out.

Thanks a lot!

```css
$primaryColor: #75beff;
$secondaryColor: #7c3702; 

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


.header {
  background: $primaryColor;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.menu-list {
 
  float: left;

}
.drop-down{
  visibility: hidden; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Ecommerce website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo"><span class="logo-text">My Fabulous store</span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li class="main-categ"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Femei</a></li>
            <div class="drop-down">
              <ul>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <li class="main-categ"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Barbati</a></li>
            <div class="drop-down">
              <ul>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <li class="main-categ"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Copii</a></li>
            <div class="drop-down">
              <ul>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <li class="main-categ"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Altele</a></li>
            <div class="drop-down">
              <ul>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Item 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="icons">
          <a href="#!">
             <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#!">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#!">
              <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="main">

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to arrange the list items from left to right

Comment: Your items already align from left to right. However, if you don't want the menu list to be in the center then you shouldn't use `space-between` (items are distributed evenly) but use `flex-start` instead. Are you wanting to align the ul inside the dropdown or outside the dropdown?

Comment: Specifically the list items with class 'main-categ'

Comment: if you want to arrange the items from left to right then the float must be applied to the items themselves rather than the ul parent, you also need to make it so that the content boxes of the dropdowns have display:none; so that their bounds do not interfere with the items

Comment: If you just want the list inside, then ignore the last comment and try `.menu-list {  display: flex; align-self: flex-start;}`

Comment: I want the items in the menu list to be aligned left to right, like in a nav bar

Comment: Happy days! It worked! Thank you! So I shouldn't have used float to begin with and should have used flexbox instead?

Comment: Yes, generally you wouldn't mix `flex` or `float`s; there's no reason and you're just complicating things. Flexbox is seen as the modern replacement to float's. You can also look at `grid`. These are all just tools to help you position things on a page. `float` has been around for decades and is still good for some situations.

Comment: @BogdanMoisa If you've solved your problem, you should write out an answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

@K.C. and @MarsAndBlack have given the right solutions:

If you just want the list inside, then ignore the last comment and try .menu-list { display: flex; align-self: flex-start;}

The problem was mixing floats and flex.

Thank you all for your help